# Navigation bar isn't showing on using Twitter for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter

For my app I have two view controllers, one where you type in the user name, and another view controller where their twitter data is displayed.

When I go from the first view controller to the second the navigation bar appears briefly before disappearing, meaning there is no way to change from the Tweet view controller to the original to search users again.

Comment: Are you using something native like SLComposeViewController or a 3rd party extension for the viewController? In theory, you should be able to just write something like self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO in the viewWillLoad or viewDidLoad ...